# How do i pass information from an activity to an edittext in a custom alertdialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have made a custom alertdialog that has 2 Edittexts in it. I want to pass information to it from an existing database when clicking something.

***this is the Custom alert dialog's class***

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_job_dialouge, null);

        builder.setView(view).setTitle("Add Job")

                .setPositiveButton("add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        if(isDouble(wageValue.getText().toString())){
                            String nameOjob = jobName.getText().toString();
                            Double valueOwage = Double.parseDouble(wageValue.getText().toString());
                            listener.applyTexts(nameOjob, valueOwage);
                            builder.create();

                        }else{
                            wageValue.setError("Wrong Format Error");
                        }

                    }
                })
                .setNeutralButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });


        jobName = view.findViewById(R.id.job_name_ETD);
        wageValue = view.findViewById(R.id.wage_ETD);

        //I want to pass information to these

        //jobName.setText();
        //wageValue.setText();

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try {
            listener =(ExampleDialogueListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + "must implement Example Dialogue Listener");
        }
    }

    public interface ExampleDialogueListener{
        void applyTexts(String jobname, Double wage);
    }

    boolean isDouble(String str) {
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(str);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I want to pass info to the edittext through parameters, so that there's info  on the edit text when I create the alertdialog

Comment: Please add all relevant information with your question. You have indicated that you have a `AlertDialog` when in fact it looks like you are implementing a `DialogFragment`. For me it would be interesting to know if you have implemented the `newInstance()` method

Comment: My bad i got confused and assumed that a custom alertdialog wasn't a fragment. And no I didn't implement the newInstance() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're extending a DialogFragment.

You can pass data in the same as you would a regular Fragment.

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("arg_key","something");
f.setArguments(args);
```

Where *f* is the instance of your DialogFragment.

Inside your DialogFragment you can call *getArguments()* to get your bundle.